# Keep Xcode from inserting copyright information in files

Tags: xcode

Whenever a new file is created in Xcode, it automatically inserts copyright information at the top of the file, like this:

```
//
//  main.m
//  dl
//
//  Created by Mark Szymanski on 5/9/11.
//  Copyright 2011 Mark Szymanski. All rights reserved.
//
```

Is there any way to stop it from doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new Xcode template that does not contain said copyright statement:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720/change-templates-in-xcode